# How to check for string changes after a user presses a Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

This question is hard to word, but explaining is easy.

I have an Activity, where a user can modify their origin and personal description.
Once all changes are made, they press the "done" Button.
Now I want to know the most optimal way of checking if the strings they entered is novel and not equal to the previous description and origin.

Because... what if they only change description, and not origin, vice versa, or they change both?
Not sure the most optimal way of doing it.

Here is my current Activity.

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private TextView originTV;
    private EditText descriptionET;
    private ImageView cameraIV, mainIV;
    private Button doneButton;
    private static final String EDIT_PROFILE = "EDIT_PROFILE";
    private UpdateUserString updateUserString;
    private int PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 20;
    private User localActivityUser;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_16e_profile_edit);
        bindActivity();
    }

    private void bindActivity()
    {
        localActivityUser = Global_Class.getInstance().getValue().user;

        originTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editProfile_originTV);
        descriptionET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editProfile_descriptionET);
        cameraIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.editProfile_cameraIV);
        mainIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.editProfile_imageIV);
        doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editProfile_doneButton);

        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!localActivityUser.getDescription().equals(descriptionET.getText().toString()))
                {
                    //Call api to update my backend.
                    UpdateUserStringAsyncTask updateUserStringAsyncTask = new UpdateUserStringAsyncTask("description",descriptionET.getText().toString());
                    updateUserStringAsyncTask.execute();
                }
                else if(!localActivityUser.getOrigin().equals(originTV.getText()))
                {
                    //Call api to update my backend
                    UpdateUserStringAsyncTask updateUserStringAsyncTask = new UpdateUserStringAsyncTask("origin",originTV.getText().toString());
                    updateUserStringAsyncTask.execute();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: `TextWatcher`? Why do you need a button to check if text has changed?

Comment: Well, if they changed the description and origin, if they press back, then i cant update their changes. So they must press done, which will update their strings in the backend, and then i will redirect them to the previous activity.

Comment: You can use the `savedInstanceState` to persist a Bundle of the values. If they press back, though, there's no telling if that was a mistake, or intentional. Forcing someone to press done (instead of cancel) is a poor design IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most optimal way would be not to care about checking every combination of valid changes, and send the whole user object to the API.  Multiple network requests is bad on your device's resources. Let the database handle updating the data, even if it is the same. That isn't a problem for your app.

```
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // These two could be in a TextWatcher instead
            localActivityUser.setDescription(
                descriptionET.getText().toString());
            localActivityUser.setOrigin(
                originTV.getText().toString());

            UpdateUserStringAsyncTask task = new UpdateUserStringAsyncTask(localActivityUser);
            task.execute();

        }
    });
```

You could also look into Android Data Binding library so that you don't need to worry about maintaining the state of the User class yourself.

Comment: Ah, yeah thats very good. I'll implement that. Thanks! saved me a lot of implementing time!